# Removing Vertexes from (non-directed) complete graph to obtain maximum number of trivial graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given a non-directed graph $G$, find the maximum set of vertexes $V'$ such that each $v$ in $V'$ is disconnected.

![Consider graph $G$ with vertexes 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and edges 6-4, 4-5, 4-5, 3-2, 5-2, 5-1, 2-1.][https://imgur.com/a/1EyYxKw].

From the above graph, removing vertexes $4$, $2$, and either vertex $5$ or $1$, would leave 3 vertices for $V'$: vertexes $6$, $3$, and either $1$ or $5$ would both be valid solutions.

Is this related to a vertex cover problem, or is this different since it is not guaranteed a vertex from every edge will be included?

As a greedy solution, I tried recursively removing the nodes with the highest connectivity / maximum number of edges until my condition was met. Will the recursive solution produce suboptimal results in some cases? What other solutions should I consider?

Comment: What is the word "complete" doing in the title of your question"

Comment: You are looking for a maximum independent (a.k.a. stable) set in $G$, which is the same thing as a maximum clique in the complementary graph.

Comment: Thanks for that! This helped my understanding [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_independent_set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_independent_set), and networkx provides an implementation to get an approximate MIS [https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.approximation.clique.maximum_independent_set.html](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.approximation.clique.maximum_independent_set.html)